# How do I enumerate child directories in WiX?

Tags: list, directory, wix, subdirectory, enumerate

I have projects with multiple installers (for installing different applications and web sites) that all install under the same parent folder (e.g. \Websites). Each of my installers calls a CustomAction that executes a C# console app (shared by all installers), passing in several parameters specific to that installer.

Each installer installs multiple web sites, each with its own folder structure (e.g. \Websites\App1, \Websites\App2, etc.).

For example, in one installer:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="WebsitesFolder">
    <Directory Id="App1Folder" Name="App1"/>
    <Directory Id="App2Folder" Name="App2"/>
</DirectoryRef>
```

And in another installer:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="WebsitesFolder">
    <Directory Id="App3Folder" Name="App3"/>
    <Directory Id="App4Folder" Name="App4"/>
    <Directory Id="App5Folder" Name="App5"/>
    <Directory Id="App6Folder" Name="App6"/>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Is there a way to enumerate the list of child directories into a comma-separated list to pass as an argument into my custom action? For example, something like the following.

```
<CustomAction Id="ConfigureWebsites" Directory="WebsitesFolder" ExeCommand="&quot;[%DEPLOYEXE]&quot; /d:&quot;[WebsitesFolder]\<list child directories here>&quot;" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" />
```

To produce the following in one installer:

```
deploy.exe /d:"C:\Websites\App1,C:\Websites\App2"
```

In the second installer:

```
deploy.exe /d:"C:\Websites\App3,C:\Websites\App4,C:\Websites\App5,C:\Websites\App6"
```

I know I can just explicitly list all the subfolders in my CustomAction, but these are growing projects and subfolders get added to these installers all the time, or the folder names may change over time, and I don't want to maintain lists of folder names in multiple places.

The reason why I want my deploy.exe to have a specific list of folders is because it will iterate through those folders and do a lot of custom tasks, and I don't want it to go through every web site under that parent folder, but only web site folders that are part of the current installation.

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerat[ing] child directories` in your custom action would be the right way to do it. WiX offers the DTF wrapper for the Windows Installer API. You can write your custom action in C# in a way that performs all of the required install, rollback, uninstall scenarios as a proper custom action should. To find the affected child directories, you would locate the Websites directory in the [Directory table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then get all the directories in the table with it as the parent. Once you have the Directory ids, get their install locations with DTF's GetTargetPath ([MsiGetTargetPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and take appropriate action for the scenario. See the DTF documentation that comes with WiX.

Or—to continue with your idea of custom actions—use an MSBuild [XslTransformation task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598688%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your .wixproj file (it's an MSBuild project file) to transform the relevant data from your .wxs file into a [WiX Include](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/preprocessor.htm) file where your CustomAction element would be defined. You could put the `XslTransformation` task in the BeforeBuild target, as explained in the comments that you'll find in the project file.  (A little bit of XSL isn't too complicated; nor a little bit of MSBuild...especially compared to Windows Installer.)

Note: To edit a project file in Visual Studio, right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select Unload. Then right-click again and select Edit.